# How to set the SeletCommand of the asp:SqlDataSource inside static method?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, static-methods

I've tried to set the SeletCommand of the asp:SqlDataSource inside static method but it's showed me "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error message.

```cs
namespace TestSPA
{
    public partial class editor1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod]
        public static string SelectDataFromSearch(string keyWord)
        {
            string result = "";

            Model.MyDataConnection mdc1 = new Model.MyDataConnection();
            OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection();
            OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand();
            conn1.ConnectionString = mdc1.ConnectonString;
            cmd1.Connection = conn1;

            try
            {
                conn1.Open();
                editor1 ed = new editor1();

                //Here is where the error line.
                ed.dsWSE.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [News] WHERE [Title] LIKE '%" + keyWord + "%' OR [Intro] LIKE '%" + keyWord + "%' OR [Story] LIKE '%" + keyWord + "%' ORDER BY [DateModified] DESC";
                //Here is where the error line.

                conn1.Close();
                result = keyWord;
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                result = err.ToString();
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

And below is my jQuery to call the above server method using Ajax

```
            $("#TxbSearch").on("keyup", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var text = $(this).val();
                console.info(text);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "editor.aspx/SelectDataFromSearch",
                    data: "{'keyWord':'" + text + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (res) {
                        console.log(res.d);

                        $("#gvNews").load(location.href + " #gvNews");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        $("#model-error-message").html(error);
                        $("#ModelError").modal('show')
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            });
```

The #TxbSearch is an ID of TextBox that has to pass it's value to the server method name "SelectDataFromSearch" while "keyup" event is occurs then update the GridView to show the search result.

Please help.

Comment: you are doing it right, dsWSE is not set in the editor1 form

Comment: You are creating a new instance of page by doing `editor1 ed = new editor1();`. That's not how should do it. You should use `<sql:Parameters>` for assigning values to parameters for command

Comment: Other way to solve is not to use static page method. But use page post back to assign Command to the SQLDataSource